# Azure APIM Backend Policy issue

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-api-management

The below mentioned backend policy in APIM to standard logic app workflow does not work, multiple instances are getting created for a single request at any given time randomly.Workflow is in VNET.

```
<backend>
<limit-concurrency key="general" max-count="1>
<forward-request timeout="240" />
</limit-concurrency>
</backend>
```

Answer (score 0):

The policy code provided by you is having syntax error. There is no closing tag for limit-concurrency after max-count attribute.

AFAIK, there is no direct way to import standard logic app. Refer this [document](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-paas-blog/import-logic-apps-standard-into-azure-api-management/ba-p/3055490) for importing logic app and adding policy.
I have reproduced issue from my side and below are steps I followed,

- Created standard logic app as shown below,
  [image]
- Added logic app in Api management by following above mentioned document.
  [image]
- Added policy in api with below code,

```
<limit-concurrency key="general" max-count="3" />
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>
```

- Tested api from api management and it triggered logic app successfully.
  [image]
  Instead of writing code manually, you can use below option and it will add code automatically.
- Click on code editor in policies,
  [image]
- Click on Hide snippets and select Limit concurrency as shwon below. Then it will add code automatically. After that set key and count.
  [image]

Comment: Hi @vijaya closing bracket is not the issue i have that in place ,have edited the code section in my question as well, the real issue is this policy ideally should restrict the concurrent request to get forwarded at the same time based on the key but i could see my logic app is triggering multiple times for a single request via apim , la is in Vnet